# ms sql подитоги под столбцам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день.  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

```
SELECT Report.PrintDate,Information.Grup
         , case sign(Report.Sum) 
              when -1 then FORMAT(Report.Sum,'N') 
              else '' end AS 'Minus'
         , case sign(Report.Sum) 
              when 1 then FORMAT(Report.Sum,'N') 
              else '' end AS 'Plus'
    FROM Report 
         INNER JOIN Information ON Report.id_info = Information.id
    WHERE PrintDate BETWEEN '15.08.2017' AND '25.08.2017' 
      AND Information.Grup = 'Москва, ТЦ Л-153, ул. Любинская, 153'
    ORDER BY Report.PrintDate,Report.ID
```

Данный запрос выводит таблицу :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя задача сделать так:

[image: 2б]

Добавить строку

На начало: В столбце Ostatok был бы подитог по всему периоду прошлого до '15.08.2017'

На конец: В столбце Ostatok был бы подитог по всему периоду с учетом '25.08.2017'

Итоги: Сумма по столбцу за этот период

Столбец Ostatok построчно вычисляет свое значение.

Или это уже за гранью фантастики и вывести не возможно? Если не возможно все то хотя бы частями что можно делать через запрос?

Comment: Немного не понял что нужно сделать

Comment: Для начала понять можно ли вы вести подитоги как показано на рисунке 2б если да то как

Comment: Т.е. в БД нет столбца Ostatok, и нужно посчитать то что вывел запрос?

Comment: ну последнюю колонку легко: `sum(Report.Sum) over(ORDER BY Report.PrintDate,Report.ID) as Ostatok` на счет дополнительных строк на начало, на конец и итогов, что то подклеить union, что то возможно собрать с помощью ROLLUP

Comment: Добрый день. Очень похоже, что вам в Excel. Вам точно нужно выводить данные в селекте в MSSQL? Потому как такая структура не очень логична. К примеру, в столбце PLUS вы выводите Итог. Т.е. в одном столбце данные с разным смыслом. З.Ы. сейчас набегут релятивисты и расскажут в чём вы не правы. :)

Comment: Да столбца Ostatok в БД нет, он полностью вычисляемый в запросе

Comment: Да, кстати, вы не указали какой именно у вас SQL. ведь оконные функции и rollup может не поддерживаться вашей БД и надо будет идти другими путями (но они всегда есть). Так что укажите какая именно БД используется и какой версии

Comment: @Deft  Если задача решить хоть частично это сильно поможет

Comment: @Deft не вижу никаких разных смыслов. итог по колонке Plus это именно сумма всех поступлений на счет

Comment: @Mike Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @Max тогда написанный мной выше sum() over() в запрос добавьте, просмотрите, он должен дать Ostatok. на счет остального сейчас подумаю.

Comment: @Mike При всём уважении к вашему опыту... не соглашусь. В результате селекта получаем таблицу, в которой в первой строке данные по 1й торговой операции, во второй строке данные по второй операции, а в третьей строке непонятное нечто, вычисляемое по формуле. В результате, использовать где либо такой результат... сложно.

Comment: @Deft В третьей строке как я понимаю такая же операция как остальные, только она в БД сидит с минусом, поэтому в другую колонку ее пишут

Comment: @Mike я имел ввиду строку №7 на последнем скрине вопроса.

Comment: Насколько всё будет проще, если формирование дополнительных записей (на начало, на конец, итоги) поручить средству отображения данных, а не средству их обработки, т.е. клиентской части, а не серверу БД... а получение нарастающего итога не должно вызвать проблем (если исходные записи имеют вменяемый признак для однозначной сортировки, чтобы не возникло проблемы при наличии полных дубликатов) - впрочем, и это можно свалить на клиента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что у вас в правой колонке, называется "Нарастающий итог" и считается по-разному, в зависимости от версии SQL Server'а.

Если предположить, что версия у вас не ниже 2012, то можно использовать оконные функции с простым синтаксисом:

```
, SUM(Report.Sum) over (order by Report.PrintDate,Report.ID) as 'Ostatok'
```

Строки в конце набора могут возвращаться разными способами. Можно использовать удобные (но сложные в освоении) операторы GROUP BY CUBE, ROLLUP, GROUPING SETS (подробнее можете прочитать здесь: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx), можно добавить запрос через union:

```
select ..
union 
select 'на конец', '', ''
         , ''
         , ''
         , sum(Report.Sum)
    FROM Report 
         INNER JOIN Information ON Report.id_info = Information.id
    WHERE PrintDate BETWEEN '15.08.2017' AND '25.08.2017' 
      AND Information.Grup = 'Москва, ТЦ Л-153, ул. Любинская, 153'
```

Comment: не совсем понял пример с union

Comment: @Max, под "select ..." понимается ваш запрос, потом следующей строчкой пишете union и все то, что я привел.

Comment: В ваш запрос уже должна быть добавлена колонка Ostatok, поскольку при объединении запросов через union количество и тип столбцов должны совпадать.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так (без структуры таблиц и образца данных в вопросе проверить запрос не представляется возможным):

```
SELECT PrintDate, Grup,
       FORMAT(sum(Minus),'N') Minus,
       FORMAT(sum(Plus),'N') Plus,
       FORMAT(max(Ostatok),'N') Ostatok
  FROM (
    SELECT Report.PrintDate,Information.Grup, Report.ID
            , case Report.Sum<0  then Report.Sum end AS Minus
            , case Report.Sum>=0 then Report.Sum end AS Plus
            , sum(Report.Sum)
                  over(ORDER BY Report.PrintDate,Report.ID) as Ostatok
      FROM Report
     INNER JOIN Information ON Report.id_info = Information.id
     WHERE PrintDate BETWEEN '15.08.2017' AND '25.08.2017' 
       AND Information.Grup = 'Москва, ТЦ Л-153, ул. Любинская, 153'
  ) X
 GROUP BY ROLLUP((PrintDate, Grup, ID))
 ORDER BY PrintDate,ID
```

Строка итогов будет со значением NULL в колонке PrintDate. в ней будут суммы по всем трем интересующим колонкам Minus, Plus и Ostatok. Двойные скобки у ROLLUP обязательны, они обеспечивают один общий итог по всей выборке, а не по каждой группе (в нашем случае строке) отдельно.

Подписывать красивые надписи, добавлять 'На начало', разбивать строку итогов на 2 'На конец' и 'Итог' рекомендую на клиенте. Выполнение этого запросе породит еще пару уровней вложенности и слишком его усложнит.